# Time complexity of the Heap pop operation

Tags: data-structures, time-complexity, heap

For a long time, I have been assuming that the time complexity of the pop operation on a Heap is `O(1)`.

Is it `O(1)` or `O(log(n))` ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)

Comment: Do you know (exactly) how pop works? The running time should be clear from there.

Comment: @Dukeling It depends in fact of the implementation. If we are using an array to implement a heap, I think we will have to rearrange values so for this case I don't think it would be `O(1)`

Comment: A heap is by definition a tree. ["a heap is a specialized tree-based data structure ... The heap is one maximally efficient implementation of an abstract data type called a priority queue, and in fact priority queues are often referred to as "heaps", regardless of how they may be implemented."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_\(data_structure\)) Although a tree can be represented as an array, if you really want to.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok `O(1)` is only for retrieving the root of the heap. To delete this root, all heap implementations have a `O(log(n))` time complexity. For example the python heapq module implements a heap with an array, and all the time the first element of the array is the root of the heap. So when deleting the root, there is a replacement process from the root down to the bottom of the heap that takes O(log(n)) time, O(log(n)) is the overall number of replacements.

[image]

Comment: You should make the distinction between the **heap**, which is an *Abstract Data Structure*, and the "binary heap", which is the simplest variant often taught in data structure courses.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog The term "abstract data structure" sounds like a confusion; a heap is a *kind* of data structure (and normally it is understood to mean a binary heap, which is a data structure), the Abstract Data Type it implements is called a priority queue.